# Data connection from Oracle financial close and consolidation to Power BI

Tags: powerbi

I am trying to get data from oracle fccs (cloud based) to power BI. From my understanding, essbase is the underlying database of oracle fccs. But I don't know from where to get essbase url. Does anyone have experience in doing so? Is my understanding correct?

Comment: You can check information in API:

https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/saas/enterprise-performance-management-common/prest/url_structure_overview.html

Comment: @msta42a Thank you for your answer. Could you please elaborate more on how to use this to connect with Power BI? I have never used API before.